# What did Jesse Pinkman mix into Walt's coffee?

Tags: breaking-bad

In  the Season 03 Episode 10 (**"Fly"**), at 25:00 to 25:40 Jesse makes coffee for Mr. White, and mixes something into it. 
He's clearly seen afraid of being caught in the act, trying to hide from Mr. White's eye while doing so.

What did he mix and what was his motive behind it?

[image: escaping Mr. White's eye]
[image: pills that he's mixing]
[image: Bottle]
[image: making sure that Mr. White hasn't watched him]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in [the episode's Wikia page](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Fly):

> Jesse prepares coffee and slips some sleeping pills into Walt's cup in an effort to force him to get some much-needed sleep. "Let the traps do the work," he says.

Comment: I'm sad that he didn't say "Let the traps do the work, bitch!"

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure he just spiked walts drink so that he would pass out and stop obsessing so that Jesse could get on with the cook

Answer (score 3):

Sleeping pills.
He wanted Walt to fall asleep so he could steal more meth. He knew Walt was on to him.